# Find radius of a tangent circle to another circle with the center on axis

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have one circle C1, its center and radius are known. And a segment AB where the points A and B are known and alwyas situated in the circle C1.
The segment AB is not a chord of the circle C1.
How to obtain the radius of the circle C2 if its center is located on the segment AB,
AND the circle C2 is tangent to the circle C1,
AND the circle C2 passing by the B point ?

I suppose there is only one solution of circle for each couple C1 and segment AB.

http://sofiasi.net/data/Yannick/tangent_circle_explanations.PNG

Comment: I'm confused. Is $AB$ meant to be a chord of the larger circle? Or is $AB$ meant to be a diameter of the larger circle? Also, some users may have trouble distinguishing the colors in your attached image. I couldn't tell the red circle apart from the black circle.

Comment: There are many such circles with different radii. You need to define the problem better.

Comment: I defined the problem better and made a new image.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have a chord AB in circle $C_1$, and this chord AB is a diameter for the circle $C_2$,this much only I understood.

Comment: AB is just a finished line, not a chord. Indeed the diameter of C2 is located on AB and the extremity of this diameter is point B

Comment: I added a new sketch for more explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Substantially revised)
Let's call the center of the big circle $U$, call its radius $r$, and the point of mutual tangency $D$. The center of the small circle (on the line $AB$) is called $C$. You can draw a picture to illustrate.

Observation 1: the distance $CD$ is the same as the distance $CB$, because $B$ and $D$ are both on the small circle.

Observation 2: the line perpendicular to the large circle at $D$ passes through $U$. That line is also perpendicular to the small circle, so it passes through $C$. Hence we have that $UC + CD = UD = r$.

So...we seek a point $C$, on the line $AB$, with $CD = CB$.

This is somewhat easier if we compute a new point, $B'$, on the line $AB$, such that the vectors $A-B$ and $B' - U$ are orthogonal.

Writing this out, we get

\begin{align}
B' 
&= (1-\alpha) B + \alpha A \\
&= B + \alpha(A- B)
\end{align}
so that 
$$
B' - U = (B-U) + \alpha(A-B).
$$
We want
$$
(B'-U) \cdot (A-B) = 0,
$$
i.e., we want to pick $\alpha$ so that
\begin{align}
0 &= (B-U)\cdot (A-B) + \alpha(A-B) \cdot (A-B) \\
\alpha(A-B) \cdot (A-B) &= -(B-U)\cdot (A-B)  \\
\alpha = \frac{-(B-U)\cdot (A-B)}{(A-B) \cdot (A-B)}  \\
\alpha = \frac{(U-B)\cdot (A-B)}{(A-B) \cdot (A-B)}.
\end{align}
We can then define $B' = B + \alpha(A-B)$ and use it going forward.

Having found this new point $B'$, we'll seek a value $t$ with 
$$
C = B' + t(A - B')
$$
that makes $CD = CB$.

Here's the picture of the current situation:
[image]
where I've also labelled some vectors that I'll define in a moment. The point $B'$ is a fraction $\alpha$ of the way from $B$ to $A$.

Now let's get to work. Let $w = B' - U$ and $v = A - B'$ and $z = C - U$ be the three vectors shown in the diagram. The outer circle radius is, you'll recall, $r$; let's define 
$$
r_0 = dist(B', B)
$$
to be the distance from $B'$ to $B$, because it'll come up again.

We want 
$$
dist(C, B) = dist(C, D)
$$
which we'll rewrite as 
$$
dist(C, B') + r_0 = r - dist(C, U)
$$
Shuffling a bit, and letting $q = r - r_0$, we get
\begin{align}
dist(C, B') + dist(C,U) &= q \\
dist(C, B') + \|z\| &= q \\
dist(C, B')  &= q - \|z\|
\end{align}

Now $C - B'$ is just the vector $tv$, and $z = w + tv$, so we want
\begin{align}
\|tv\|  &= q - \|w + tv\|
\end{align}
which I'll rewrite as 
\begin{align}
\|w + tv\|  &= q - \|tv\|
\end{align}

Squaring both sides, we get
\begin{align}
\|w + tv\|^2  &= (q - \|tv\|)^2 \\
(w + tv) \cdot (w + tv)  &= (q - t\|v\|)^2 \\
w \cdot w + 2t w \cdot v +  &= q^2 - 2t q \|v\|.
\end{align}
Now recalling that we chose $B'$ exactly so that $w$ and $v$ would be perpendicular, we get $w \cdot v = 0$, so this becomes
\begin{align}
w \cdot w  &= q^2 - 2t q \|v\| \\
2tq \|v\|  &= q^2 - w \cdot w \\
t &= \frac{ q^2 - w \cdot w }{2q\|v\|}.
\end{align}
So that gives us the coordinates of $C$:
$$
C = B' + t(A-B')
$$
where $t$ is given by the formula above. Here's all that written out in working Matlab code; the only subtlety is that $B'$ is denoted `Bp` in the code. You can experiment with this by varying the first coordinate of $B$. You'll want to see what happens when you make it so large that it's outside the magenta circle, and what happens when it's exactly ON the magenta circle. It'd be a good idea for you to figure out what SHOULD happen in each of those cases before you run the program, though.

```
function mse3571854()
% solution to 
% https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571854/find-radius-of-a-tangent-circle-to-another-circle-with-the-center-on-axis/3573574?noredirect=1#comment7349658_3573574
%close all; % close any figures left open from prior runs

U = [10, -20];         % put the circle near the origin
r = 70;            % with radius 100
B = [30, 50]+ U;       % pick a spot for B to kinda match the drawing in the q.
A = [-40, 50]+ U;      % and same for A, at the same height to make it pretty
figure(1);          % open up a first window to draw in. 
s = linspace(0, 2*pi, 400);     % generate 400 numbers from 0 to 2pi
circlex = U(1) + r * cos(s);           % and compute (r cos(a), r sin(a) ) for each
circley = U(2) + r * sin(s);           % creating 400 points on a circle of radius r
plot(circlex, circley, 'm');    % plot those, in magenta
hold on;                        % and when you plot more, don't erase what's there!
plot( [A(1), B(1)], [A(2), B(2)], 'r'); % now draw the line from A to B in red
plot( [A(1), B(1)], [A(2), B(2)], 'ro');% and put a little red circle at each end
set(gca, 'DataAspectRatio', [1,1,1]);   % tell matlab to make the X- and y-coordinate
figure(gcf);                    % scales the same, so the circle's round; bring the figure
                            % to the front, and then
hold off;                       % turn off the "hold" so that fresh plots will
                            % overdraw the current one. 
% Now start doing what the answer says... 



alpha = dot(U-B, A-B) / dot(A-B,A-B);
Bp = (1-alpha)*B + alpha * A; 
r0 = length(Bp - B);

q = r - r0; 
v = A - Bp; 
w = Bp - U; 

t = (q^2 - dot(w,w)) / (2 * q * length(v));
C = (1-t)*Bp + t * A; 

r2 = length(C - B); % radius of smaller circle
circle2x = C(1) + r2 * cos(s);
circle2y = C(2) + r2 * sin(s); 

z = C - U;
h = z / length(z);
D = U + r * h;

figure(2);
plot(circlex, circley, 'm');    % Replot the stuff above
hold on;                        
plot( [A(1), B(1)], [A(2), B(2)], 'r'); 
plot( [A(1), B(1)], [A(2), B(2)], 'ro');

plot( [C(1)], [C(2)], 'bo'); % plot C as a blue dot
plot( [D(1)], [D(2)], 'ko'); % plot D as a black dot
plot( [Bp(1)], [Bp(2)], 'co'); % plot Bp as an cyan dot
plot( [U(1)], [U(2)], 'ko'); % plot U as a black dot
plot(circle2x, circle2y, 'b'); % plot the second circle
hold off;
set(gca, 'DataAspectRatio', [1,1,1]);   
figure(gcf);

function q = length(u)
q = sqrt(dot(u, u));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how to obtain the value of the radius of the small circle, I'm a bit puzzled with maths...

Comment: From $UC + CD = r$, you get that $CD$, which is the radius of the small circle, is just $r - UC$, where $UC$ is the distance from $U$ to $C$.

Comment: Thank you John, I understood that and all you made, but my problem is to turn it in practice that. I.e.how to compute coordinates from the points to get x, y coordinate of the small circle center. Sorry if my question is stupid but I'm just turning around it without success

Comment: Thanks John, as I said in my definition, B will never be on magenta circle nor outside of this circle. Anyway, here is the result of the code above in MathLab for figure 2, I think there is a mistake somewhere : http://sofiasi.net/data/Yannick/MathLab_2.PNG

Comment: I failed to paste in the definition of the (local) function "length" (which should probably be called "vlength" (for "vector length") or something, to avoid conflict with the global name "length", which has to do with the number of items in an array I believe. Anyhow, I've now included it, and things work fine.

Comment: I do worry that you're neither reading the mathematics in the answer carefully (in which case you'd have seen the error in my first version --- setting $CB = CU$ rather than $CB = CD)$) nor the code. I suppose that's a choice you get to make, but when there's a problem (or you need to generalize), you're gonna be in trouble...

Comment: Thanks you for your help and patience

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

Given are $ (a,XB,yB,m)$

Let the big circle wlog be

$$x^2+y^2= a^2 \tag1 $$

Let the slope of tangent line be $m$

$$\frac{yB-yC}{xB-xC}=m \tag2 $$

Plug into required circle

$$ (x-xC)^2+(y-yC)^2= b^2 \tag3$$

and eliminate either $x$ or $y$ from above to get a quadratic equation.

From this result set quadratic equation discriminant to zero, then configuration is fully solved.

Comment: Thank you very much for your work but I'm totaly unable to get by myself a quadradic equation, help is wanted for this

Comment: The surprising thing (to me, anyhow!) is (as you can see from my solution) that the "quadratic" actually turns out to be linear (or the square of a linear form, depending on how you do things). So there's a single solution rather than two.